# Which mongo driver for node should I use?

Tags: mongodb, node.js

[The Node wiki](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-db-nosql-mongo) lists a few different mongo driverrs for node. What are the pros and cons on each one?

Right now I want to efficiently tail a Mongo capped collection from node, but I suspect I will end up using mongo from node quite heavily and if stackoverflow can save me from having to switch to a different driver later that'd be great.

In general I have no particular interest in object relational mappers; I mainly want to make clean and efficient insert, update and find calls asynchronously.

Comment: also see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/node.JS

Answer (score 9):

It's hard to say which is the best.

My current favorites from the api-sugar point of view are:

- [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com) as a ODM
- [Mongoskin](https://github.com/guileen/node-mongoskin) witch basically replaces the driver's callbacks-based api with one based on promises (when/then)

Comment: Honestly, at this point it's hard to say which is the best and which will become the main choice.  
I also went with Mongoose and find it to be perfectly adequate.  It has some bugs to do with Setters at the moment, but other than that it does a job and does it well.

Comment: Yeah two good choices.  I'd say go with Mongoose if you want schemas, models with logic etc., go with Mongoskin if you want raw performance and flexibility.